# How can I install .deb files that look like a sealed box in the file folder to install on my ubuntu 16.04 lts desktop

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

i have successfully downloaded a file, but the file does not open when in the folder, these are all .deb files and the icon is like a sealed box,

Comment: try sudo apt install /path/to/whatever.deb or  right click on > Open With Software Install

Comment: @doug Isn't it `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/whatever.deb` ?

Comment: In 16.04 apt can resolve dependencies so it's a decent choice over dpkg which can't (- there are a few corner cases where apt won't work & dpkg is a potentially better  choice

Answer (score -1):

The .deb file is an application install package.  The sealed box you see is a visual showing it's a package.

**You can install the package by double clicking on it.**

When you double click the file, it should bring up the software center and give you a graphical interface with a button to click install.

You can also right click on the icon and choose the install program installer to run.

**Alternately you can install a deb package from the commandline with:**

```
$ sudo dpkg -i [packagename.deb]
```